# Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Tags: запятая

И первое и второе можно быстро сделать в автоматическом режиме.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя есть такое правило: "При двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом "и" запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство: Он ею и жил и дышал". В Вашем предложении как раз такой случай. Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

"Смысловое единство" тут крайне сомнительно (как сомнителен и сам термин "смысловое единство"). А если есть сомнения, то применяем общее правило.

Вывод - запятая нужна!

Comment: В сомнительных случаях можно сделать проверку с помощью интонации. Пожалуйста, составьте интонационную схему для этого предложения при наличии запятой. Мне кажется, это очень трудно сделать. Мы должны выразить сочинительную связь в начале предложения, тогда получится: "И первое (пауза), и второе (короткая пауза, перелом интонации) можно сделать в автоматическом режиме". Это неудобно для произношения. Если  не применять интонационный анализ, то структуру предложения можно проверить с помощью замены: и то и другое. Здесь нет запятой.

Comment: Проверять интонацией -- удел избранных. Шучу. Но вижу в этом толику правды.
По сути, такие правила перестают быть точной рекомендацией и вводят нас в область субъективного. Да и писать становится труднее. То пишешь, то вслух интонируешь. 
Короче, я вообще против сложных правил. Они попросту недемократичны, недоступны большинству. Зачем язык превращать в удел спецов? Он должен принадлежать народу ;-))

Comment: Когда мы говорим об интонации, речь не идет о выражениях "каким тоном ты со мной разговариваешь". Речь идет о простейших интонационных моделях, доступных для понимания даже младшим школьникам. Это всего лишь расстановка пауз и деление речи на фразы восходящего или нисходящего тона, которые просто надо услышать в речи  и обозначить знаками пунктуации. Это гораздо проще, чем заучивать как демократичные, так и недемократичные правила.